# Removing edges from a digraph to obtain the smallest digraph

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

Say that I have a connected digraph $D$ composed by $N$ nodes and $E$ edges, and a root node `root`. Assume now that I want to play the following game: I remove $K$ edges from  $D$ (with $K < E$), and then remove any node that is not reachable from the root.

Which $K$ edges should I choose to have the smallest resulting graph $D$ at the end?

Can this game be reduced to any known graph problems?

Comment: Does it matter for the problem that the graph is directed? If it were an undirected graph, I would say you're looking for the smallest set of nodes that contains your root node _and_ such that there are at most $k$ edges between nodes in the set and nodes outside of it.

Comment: Yeah, that is another good way to formulate the same problem. Are you aware of any approach/solution to solve it?

Comment: Does it matter for the problem that the graph is directed? Which difinition of "connected" are you using when you remove nodes?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary for `D` to be a digraph. A node `n`, in my game, is disconnected if there is no path from the root of the graph to the node `n`. If easier, I can generalize the problem to generic graphs.

Comment: Okay. Does my edit preserve your intention?

Comment: My gut feeling says there ought to be a way to reduce this to something like a sequence of maximum-flow problems, but the details are slippery.

Comment: yes, it does. Thanks.

Comment: In the case of a tree you can just cut the $K$ edges from root that disconnects the largest number of nodes... not sure if this helps though